# How to create a link in html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, instagram

How to create a link like Instagram username or hashtag in php or javascript ?
I used to use these codes before`

str_ireplace('@', '@', 'I @aaaa  in');
`
But all the words are converted to a link.
And can i add a python library to javascript or php?

Comment: Can we have some context? Are you using JavaScript to add these to your HTML?

Comment: Can we also see your HTML?

Comment: This is very long and i have problem for to past code

Comment: I used php and html and javascript

Comment: With no HTML code, it will be very difficult to supply code that would be benefit your current project structure. I will have a go assuming you used PHP to insert the usernames

Answer (score 0):

So assuming you inserted your usernames with PHP, the html structure could look similar to this.

HTML:

```
<p class="username">@Username</p>
<p class="username">@otherUser</p>
<p class="username">@meAndYou</p>
```

JavaScript + JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    changeUserNames();
}
function changeUserNames(){
 $('p').each(function (index) {
   var text = $(this).text();
   var username = text.split('@')[1];
   $(this).html(`@<a href="link/${username}">${username}</a>`);
 });
}
```

JS Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/zy46npb2/4/

Comment: Thanks you , but i will search in text and find word and it change to a link.